# How to install Angular2 universal when the docs on the site are outdated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-universal

The maintainers at [angular2-universal](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/) have not updated their site:

Problem 1)

```
typings install node express body-parser serve-static express-serve-static-core mime --ambient
typings ERR! deprecated The "ambient" flag is deprecated. Please use "global" instead
```

Problem 2)

```
    typings install node express body-parser serve-static express-serve-static-core mime --global
typings INFO globaldependencies "express" lists global dependencies on "node" that must be installed manually
typings INFO globaldependencies "body-parser" lists global dependencies on "node" that must be installed manually
typings ERR! message Unable to find "node" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "node" for 2 other sources: "dt" and "env"
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/node/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /Users/davidmontgomery/Documents/frontend/green
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.6.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "node" "express" "body-parser" "serve-static" "express-serve-static-core" "mime" "--global"
typings ERR! node -v v4.5.0
typings ERR! typings -v 1.3.3

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

How do I resolve? I am using a mac.

Comment: Hey! Don't forget to select the right answer for your question ;-)

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to install node separately with the `--global` flag, because it's the only one that needs to be installed globally.

```
typings install dt~node --global
typings install dt~express dt~body-parser dt~serve-static dt~express-serve-static-core dt~mime
```

**EDIT :**
You don't need angular universal for server side rendering anymore, as it is now part of angular core.

Comment: What is meant by "angular core"?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.0 TypeScript Definition Manager made some updates ([see here][1]) which included deprecating the `--ambient` flag.

> - Usages of ambient are now global
>
>   - That means in `typings.json` any `ambientDependencies` should be renamed `globalDependencies` and any `ambientDevDependencies` should be
>       renamed `globalDevDependencies`.
>   - It also means `--ambient` is now `--global`
>       ...

=> For more information, check this out.
     [typings github]: https://github.com/typings/typings
     [original answer]: [Ambient flag is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808614/ambient-flag-is-deprecated)

**Thus, you should use this pattern ↓**

`typings install dt~PackageName --save --global`

ex) `typings install dt~body-parser --global --save`

Comment below, if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of things changing across typescript and the universal team working overtime to updating universal to the latest releases of angular rc5 and rc6, things have fallen a bit behind on the documentation front.
If you want to get started quickly, checkout out the universal starter kit at https://github.com/angular/universal-starter that should work for you.