# Install Angular 2 Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, express, webpack-dev-server

**Updated:**

I'm trying to install Angular 2 Universal using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366601/how-to-install-angular2-universal-when-the-docs-on-the-site-are-outdated)  guide but when I run the following command I get some errors.

Here is the command:

```
typings install node express body-parser serve-static dexpress-serve-static-core mime --global --save
```

And the errors are:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\myApp>typings install node express body-parser serve-static dexpress-serve-static-core mime --global --save
typings INFO globaldependencies "express" lists global dependencies on "node" that must be installed manually
typings INFO globaldependencies "serve-static" lists global dependencies on "node" that must be installed manually
typings INFO globaldependencies "body-parser" lists global dependencies on "node" that must be installed manually
typings ERR! message Unable to find "node" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "node" for 2 other sources: "dt" and "env"
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/node/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
typings ERR!
typings ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\myApp
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 10.0.14393
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install" "node" "express" "body-parser" "serve-static" "dexpress-serve-static-core" "mime" "--global" "--save"
typings ERR! node -v v6.9.2
typings ERR! typings -v 2.0.0
typings ERR!
typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

I'm using node version v6.9.2 and npm 4.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Update nodeJS, simply download the LTS version on their [homepage](https://nodejs.org/en/), install it, then update npm too:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

And try again your first command, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I've updated both nodejs and npm to the latest recommended versions but still get errors.See the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Angular Universal by the following way:

1. Download starter project: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter
2. Install NPM in the project folder using terminal or your IDE. For Mac the command is:

   > sudo npm install

It is important to use "sudo" with the password otherwise then you can have some errors with access.

3. Run

   > npm start
4. Go to **localhost:3000**.